# How can I know recently asked questions by others for particular tags?

Tags: support, feature-request, tags, questions, notifications

I want to answer the recently asked questions first than others. But I don't know how to find the questions. Is there any option to get a notification when others post a question for particular tags?

Comment: I'm not sure I would like a notification every time someone asks a question with my favorite tags. Then I would get about about 500 notifications every day.

Comment: Checkout StackExchange filters - https://stackexchange.com/filters

Comment: RSS feeds are exactly for this. Example, for Forth: *[`http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=forth&sort=newest`](http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=forth&sort=newest)*. Partial (cross-site) duplicate: *[Any way to get an RSS feed of 'newest' tagged questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10140)*. For a more elaborate overview, see also *[What other hidden or inobvious RSS feeds are available on Stack Exchange and its sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151519)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notifications are not (so far) implemented. And I believe it'd be a nice feature.

Now, to simply keep track on new questions of particular tag, you can have a tab like this open:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift

Toggle to newest tab:
[image: Newest]

The page is updated real-time.
Obviously it doesn't guarantee you are the first to know about the new question (as it requires you to constantly check), but at least it lets to track.

So yes, some notification system would be handy.

**Favorite tags**

Also note that on the same page (essentially a home page) you can add favorite tags (see caption on the right) and then click them to check updates. Hint: you can add variations / synonyms of an interesting tag and quickly toggle between.

[image: fav tags]

Comment: Note that you can aggregate multiple tags on one page (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift+or+ios+or+viper). That way you can get notified on a single page for any of the tags you're interested in. On Firefox, if you pin such a page, it lights up blue as soon as the page is changed (new questions are added).

Comment: You can add `?sort=newest` to the bookmarked URL to always go to that tab without having to manually toggle.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth thanks, didn't know about `or` in url, would be handy

Answer (score 5):

There’s a [Google Chrome extension called StackNotifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stacknotifier-stackoverfl/dkicpibgdednbmlclkbcehckpfficabn) that works pretty well. Here’s its config UI:

[image: Stack Notifier config UI]

Give it a semicolon-separated list of tags you want notifications for, specify how often you want to check for new questions in those tags, and then whenever a new question’s posted to one of those tags, you get a desktop notification with the question title that you can click to see the question.